# BrowserSync Proxy not Loading Page

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm doing some local development using `gulp`, 'nodemon' and `browsersync`. I have defined the following gulp task to kick-off nodemon and start browsersync:

```
    gulp.task('develop', function() {
    return nodemon({
        script: './bin/server/server.js',
        ext: 'js',
        env: {
            PORT: port
        },
        watch: __dirname + '/bin/server/**/*'
    })
        .on('start', function() {
            startBrowserSync();
        })
        .on('restart', function () {
            browserSync.reload();
        });
});

function startBrowserSync(){
    if (browserSync.active){
        return;
    }

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost:" + port + "/app/client",
        online: true
    });

}
```

The server starts on `localhost:8000`, and browsersync attempts to load the proxy `localhost:3000/app/client`. This is the IDE console output

```
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:8000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/app/client
    External: http://false:3000/app/client
 ---------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://false:3001
 ---------------------------------------------
server running on port: 8000
```

However, the browser just sits there churning over and not displaying anything (no reports in the browser debug console). If I load `localhost:8000/app/client` directly, I get my web page. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, so edited `init` to read `init({proxy: { target: "localhost:" + port + "/app/client"}})` and all seems to be working.

Comment: hmmm, stopped working again, even with the above edit. Strange intermittent behaviour this.